# How to change programmatically the background color of in tvOS in Swift?

Tags: swift, user-interface, background, tvos

I would like to change programmatically the color of the background in the main view (I'm creating an app with Swift).I tryed to put this code in viewDidLoad() but it doesn't work. What is the correct way to do this?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
   ...
   let myBackground = UIView()
   let colorWhite = UIColor(red: 255, green: 255, blue: 255, alpha: 1)
   myBackground.backgroundColor = colorWhite
   ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are creating a new subview, which is not added to your view stack yet. Instead, it's much simpler:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    // Or with RGB:
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 142 / 255.0, green: 142 / 255.0, blue: 147 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)
}
```

Comment: Hi Antoine, thank you for your post. The code works fine if I use presets component value. And if I would like to use a custom color like: red: 142, green: 142, blue: 147, alpha: 1 how you suggest to proceed?

Answer (score 2):

Also you can change the background color depends on what time people do watch (AM or PM):

```
var t = time(nil)
    var tmValue = tm()
    localtime_r(&t, &tmValue)
    let hour = tmValue.tm_hour
    if hour > 12 {
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.brownColor()
    } else {
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    }
```